# How to get selected and creatable value in AutoComplete (Material UI). I bind Data from onChange method to setState but this is not what I expected

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

I want to get AutoComplete onChange data. I got data from onChange((e,value) => console.log(value).

But how to put data on State .

This AutoComplete component behaviour is (Creatable and selectable) . I got all data on onChange but on in the state, If I set the data on State , selectOnFocus is not working.

How to get rid of that?
Thank you

`

```js
    <Autocomplete
              multiple
              limitTags={5}
              onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                setToEmails(newValue);
              }}
              filterOptions={(options, params) => {
                const filtered = filter(options, params);
                if (params.inputValue !== "") {
                  filtered.push({
                    inputValue: params.inputValue,
                    label: `Add "${params.inputValue}"`,
                    value: nanoid(7),
                  });
                }
                return filtered;
              }}
              selectOnFocus
              blurOnSelect
              clearOnBlur
              handleHomeEndKeys
              id="free-solo-with-text-demo"
              options={toBlockers}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => {
                if (typeof option === "string") {
                  return option;
                }
                if (option.inputValue) {
                  return option.inputValue;
                }
                return option.label;
              }}
              renderOption={(option) => option.label}
              freeSolo
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Blockers" variant="outlined" />
              )}
            />
```

`

If I use this , Selectable is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Later on I got solved by myself . This took about 3 days ,

here is full example of Creatable with selectable with formData thing.

```js
        
    const [toEmails, setToEmails] = useState([]);      
     
     
     //if you want to post this data on formData , you have structured this way
     
         const appendedObject = [
      { label: "_creative", value: "node_process_Lh1L8RsafJbUas" },
      { label: "Azim__bro", value: "node_process_LhL1s8RaafJbUas" },
    ];
    const finalBlockers = [...appendedObject, ...toEmails];
    formData.append("attachmentList", []);
    console.log({ toEmails, finalBlockers });
    if (finalBlockers) {
      for (const blocker of finalBlockers) {
        console.log({ blocker });
        formData.append("blockers", JSON.stringify(blocker));
      }
    }
     
     
        
        <Autocomplete
              multiple
              limitTags={5}
              getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
                const optionTitle =
                  typeof option === "string" ? option : option.value;
                const valueTitle =
                  typeof value === "string" ? value : value.value;
                return optionTitle === valueTitle;
              }}
              onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                if (Array.isArray(newValue)) {
                  const updatedArrayValue = newValue.filter((e) =>
                    typeof e === "string" ? e.trim() : e
                  );
                  const newArrayValue = [...updatedArrayValue];
                  const updatedArray = newArrayValue.map((item) => {
                    if (typeof item === "string") {
                      const newItem = {};
                      newItem.label = item;
                      newItem.value = nanoid(12);
                      newItem.type = "created";
                      return newItem;
                    }
                    return item;
                  });
                  setToEmails(updatedArray);
                }
              }}
              filterOptions={(options, params) => {
                const filtered = filter(options, params);
                if (params.inputValue !== "") {
                  filtered.push({
                    inputValue: params.inputValue,
                    title: `Add "${params.inputValue}"`,
                    value: nanoid(12),
                    type: "created",
                  });
                }
                return filtered;
              }}
              selectOnFocus
              clearOnBlur
              handleHomeEndKeys
              id="free-solo-with-text-demo"
              options={toBlockers}
              filterSelectedOptions
              getOptionLabel={(option) => {
                // Value selected with enter, right from the input
                if (typeof option === "string") {
                  return option;
                }
                // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
                if (option.inputValue) {
                  return option.inputValue;
                }
                // Regular option
                return option.label;
              }}
              renderOption={(option) => option.label}
              freeSolo
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Blockers" variant="outlined" />
              )}
            />
```